# Make an alias or shortcut to do more than one command several times

Tags: shell-script

Example:

```
rm -rf /sdcard/example
mkdir -p /sdcard/example
echo "example" > /sdcard/example/example.txt
chmod -Rf 777 /sdcard/example
echo "Done"
```

Instead of typing that again inside my shell-script (bash)
I want to do all of the echo in a single command like a shortcut
Is there a way to do that?
Tried to do this but not work

```
alias EXAMPLE="rm -rf /sdcard/example
mkdir -p /sdcard/example
echo "example" > /sdcard/example/example.txt
chmod -Rf 777 /sdcard/example
echo "Done""
```

But it's doesn't work when I input the EXAMPLE command
Sorry for bad english

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias; also, join the commands with `&&` so if one fails, it doesn't blindly continue through the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just figured it out

`CR()
{
rm -rf /sdcard/example
mkdir -p /sdcard/example
echo "example" > /sdcard/example/example.txt
chmod -Rf 777 /sdcard/example
echo "Done"
}`